# amcharts custom period date

Tags: javascript, amcharts

AmCharts have some defaults formats for dates:

```
[{period:'fff',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
 {period:'ss',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
 {period:'mm',format:'JJ:NN'},
 {period:'hh',format:'JJ:NN'},
 {period:'DD',format:'MMM DD'},
 {period:'WW',format:'MMM DD'},
 {period:'MM',format:'MMM'},
 {period:'YYYY',format:'YYYY'}]
```

I can use `categoryAxis.minPeriod = "DD";` like in example below.

```js
categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.00;
categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0.30;
categoryAxis.inside = false;
categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
categoryAxis.title = gon.graph_info.horizontal_label
categoryAxis.parseDates = true
categoryAxis.minPeriod = "DD";
```

But I want to define or use periods with formats for **four weeks**, **six month**, etc in way that I can write like below

```js
categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.00;
categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0.30;
categoryAxis.inside = false;
categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
categoryAxis.title = gon.graph_info.horizontal_label
categoryAxis.parseDates = true
categoryAxis.minPeriod = "TOW_MONTHS";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, this should be possible to do with the `minPeriod` property of the category axis. See http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod

> It's also possible to supply a number for increments, i.e. "15mm" which will instruct the chart that your data is supplied in 15 minute increments.

In the case of two months, it should be `2MM`